# Eclipse linking JDK

Tags: eclipse, classpath, java

I have extracted Eclipse on my C partition. I got windows 7 64 bits. Eclipse is 64 bits. But JDK is 32 bit. Once I run eclipse the pop menu is saying it can't find JDK or JRE on some sort of path. Once I run Eclipse from USB drive it works fine. What is the problem? Should I specify envorinmont variables, set classpath or something? What exactly should I do?
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get the 64bit JDK?

Comment: I have seen only 32 bits JDK for v7.

Comment: Well, look again:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you download any java jdk on your pc? To check, open a command prompt and launch the command `java -version` then `javac -version` If one of them fails, you need to download java jdk from oracle's website

Comment: I have downloaded the JDK 7 from Oracle Web site together with NetBEans. Both checks fail, but this is not the first time. I just need to specify the path to each app (java, javac) and it will gradually work fine. As it happended and before.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you are using windows then i will recommend you to download `Windows x86 jdk-7u5-windows-i586.exe`.

**2.** Install it... in C:\Program Files\Java\

**3.** Include this in your `System PATH` **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin** .

**3.** Then type `java -version` in your command prompt, and if you get the version of your JDK then, you have properly installed the java, and your path is properly configured.

**4.** Extract your Eclipse folder from the Eclipse.rar downloaded from Eclipse site.

**5.** You can place this Extracted Eclipse folder anywhere in the disk, but i recommend you to store it in c: drive as this `C:\Program Files\eclipse`

**6. Now i think it should work.............**

Comment: I set a path at Environment Variables window, but it did not cause a change.

Answer (score 0):

In a command prompt, a `java -version` should show the details of the installed JVM.

For example, a jdk7 32-bit version would show this:

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

A jdk7 64-bit version would show this:

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

However, the standard JDK installation copies the `java.exe`  and `javaw.exe` on the `c:\Windows\System32` folder, which could be the ones that Eclipse looks for. This could get really messy if you've tried to re-install different JDK versions and you loose track of the last one you installed (or like me, if you install different versions for backwards support on some legacy projects).

To be 100% sure of the JVM used by your Eclipse, just modify the `eclipse.ini` file located in your `eclipse/` folder so it points to the exact JVM you want. For example, add these lines if you want to use your jdk7 64-bit (check if the same folder applies):

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javaw.exe
```

Start Eclipse, and it should work fine.

Go to [this site](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) fore more info on the `eclipse.ini` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial is the only thing that worked for me with Win 64 bit.

Summary:
install

- 32 bit eclipse
- 32 bit JDK (NOT JRE)
- 32 bit Android SDK

Add Java to your PATH environmental variable

open eclipse.ini and add a line pointing to the JDK

I uninstalled all versions of Java from my system first.

http://envyandroid.com/archives/38/getting-started-with-android-dev-environment